# Shortcut to search for package in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> searches for class names.  Is there a way to search for a package name across multiple projects in a workspace?  I consulted several shortcut pages, such as [this one](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) but could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for a folder, Ctrl-Shift-N (search for file) > type name with "/" on the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really a single shortcut, but a combination:

Ctrl-Shift-F (find in path) > Ctrl-P (group by package)